# Is it possible to "compile out" stream expressions in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, c-preprocessor

It is well established that you can use macros to make a version of `printf` that can be stripped from the code during compilation (say, if you want to only print on debug builds).  The resulting code can be used exactly like one would use `printf`.

**Is it possible to produce a similar scenario with respect to stream output?**

For example, suppose I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    Foo& operator <<(const T& input)
    {
        std::cout << input;
    }
};

int ComputeExpensiveThing(); // this function is expensive

void doSomething()
{
    Foo() << "Expensive thing:  " << ComputeExpensiveThing() << std::endl;
    // do other things
}
```

**Is there a way to conditionally strip the first line of doSomething() at compile-time?**

I can use a macro to get a similar effect by checking a global condition at runtime:

```
#define FOO if(!someGlobalCondition); else Foo()

void doSomething()
{
    FOO << "Expensive thing:  " << ComputeExpensiveThing() << std::endl;
}
```

However, this requires a conditional branch instruction each time we use `FOO`.  It's a significant improvement over calling `ComputeExpensiveThing`, but I'd still prefer to remove the excess branches.

I've also seen an alternative that changes the target syntax to something like

```
void doSomething()
{
    Foo("Expensive thing:  " << ComputeExpensiveThing() << std::endl);
}
```

but the resulting syntax is a bit odd and unintuitive to some users.

Comment: it might be best to split this into separate questions

Comment: @djs: I see only one question here. What's the other one (that should be split off)?

Comment: The second bolded question is meant to be a specifc example clarifying the meaning of the first one.  Apologies if it was confusing!

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just make the conditional something like this?

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbglog std::cout
#else
#define dbglog if(0) std::cout
#endif
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
dbglog << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
```

`if(0)` and the subsequent statement will be completely deleted by the compiler (clang even does this optimization with no `-O` flag specified!).

Comment: The compiler can only optimize out `ComputeExpensiveThing()` if it is sure that the function doesn't have any side effects. With a complex computation that might not be the case.

Comment: Something that worked with existing code bases and didn't require modifying every call site would be *nice* (but maybe not possible).

Comment: Well, if you are already using e.g. `cout` then you could in principle substitute it using a macro. The term "existing code bases" is quite broad though; it is very possible that many existing code bases will already be using custom logging, which could be easily retrofit using my answer.

Comment: This should be fine if (a) the compiler really does elide the if(constexpr) statement and (b) we never want to use dbglog itself as an expression.  I'd prefer something that works without relying on the optimizer, but this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a good c++ programer, and I could easily be wrong.

But shouldn't it be exactly the same if you defined a `const debug` and just do `if (debug) do_something;`. I'm gathering that compilers love [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) and it would evaluate all the `if`s before time and there would be no branches created at all.

If that would be correct, then it's also a good chance that you won't risk compiler ignoring inlining your function (which I also gather sometimes can happen for complex functions?).

However, this is something completely compiler related so I can't claim universality.

Comment: That's a good point.  So long as the test condition is a constant expression, if the compiler is at all good at its job, it ought to simply elide the `if` statement entirely.  This may end up being a "dig into the assembly" situation rather than a "use evil/clever (clevil?) macro tricks" one.